# Python3 FileNotFoundError with any file, using subprocess.popen()

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, pickle, popen

Iv'e been trying to load data from a pickle file for use with pySpark on Windows

Here's my code:

```
import subprocess
import pickle

proc = subprocess.Popen(["cat", "./users-partition.pickle"],
                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
pickle_content = proc.communicate()[0]
partition = pickle.loads(pickle_content)
len(partition)
```

Iv'e been searching the web for hours to make this work, but no luck still.
The error message (for line 3) is:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Tried with all kinds of files, all inside the current working directory for certain.
Would appreciate any help! Thank you!!

Comment: It looks like you are on Windows.  Do you have a program called `cat.exe` on your `%PATH%`?

Comment: Also, why are you trying to run a subprocess to cat a pickle file?

Comment: 1. Cheked and found not such value in the path variable
2. It's part of a py script for big data analisys course home assignment, just following the script really

Comment: @VictorMartinov you should open the pickle file with `open()` and then `read()` it, or `pickle.load(open("./users-partition.pickle", "rb"))`

Comment: @BrianCain thanks, the
`pickle.load(open("./users-partition.pickle", "rb"))`
command seems to work as desired! I guess the original script assumes the OS is linux, that's why it didn't work (no "cat" command on windows).

Comment: I still don't understand--there's literally no reason you would call `cat` in a subprocess to read a file...  Where did you get this script?

Comment: @Iguananaut The script is from a "Big Data Analytics using Spark" course, from one of its' home assignments

Comment: That's enough common terms that that title alone isn't really enough to know what you're talking about. But I think you should contact it's authors and point them to this post, because this is seriously wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using cat which might not exist in your path as you are on windows. You could just use pythons built in file handling.

```
file = open('./users-partition.pickle','r')
text = file.read()
```

The variable 'text' would contain everything cat would have returned at that point. Learn more here:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_open.asp

Comment: thanks! but those commands did not read the pickle file as desired (dictionary format). 
the command `pickle.load(open("./users-partition.pickle", "rb"))` did better in this case.